# Dealing with modal popups in Dynamics GP when running as a Remote Application in Terminal Services

Tags: remote-desktop, popups, odbc

Running GP10 as a Remote Application in Terminal Servers (W2K8).  The multi-analysis tool requires ODBC credentials, when it executes against the database, to build the data cube.

Unfortunately, being a remote application and not a remote desktop connection - these modal popups are not coming to the foreground and therefore the user is unable to populate the form and thus the reporting tool "appears to hang".

Is there a way of configuring the tool or GP to save these credentials?  It is not an option to install the GP application as a fat client, as we also have a legacy version of GP still installed and required on the users PC's - and we have made significant investment and other design decisions based on a powerful terminal server.

Your thoughts and ideas please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue, [there is a hotfix available from Microsoft under KB983533](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983533/en-us).